# QTP How to record context menu

Tags: .net, winforms, qtp, automated-tests

I tried recording a case in winforms. All works fine until a context menu is generated on the form.
The idea is to select the 2nd option in the conext menu and move to the next step.
QTP records all steps but misses the context menu step. while running the case the context menu is generated and QTP hangs. Its not able to select the context menu and doesnt move to the next step.

I found this on some blog :

```
SwfWindow("Form1").WinMenu("contextMenuStrip1").Select DataTable("option1ToolStripMenuItem", dtGlobalSheet)
```

But it doesnt work. I get an error "*The "contextMenuStrip1"  object was not found in the Object Repository.*"

Its a simple winform (rightclick) contextmenustrip control. I am using QTP 11 and VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is QTP doesn’t record the contextmenustrip step. While running the test QTP faces a context menu and doesn’t know what to do and hangs.

This can be solved with the following step : while recording the steps when the context menu opens up Right Click to select the option on the context menu.

This generates code similar to the following :

```
SwfWindow("Form1").SwfToolbar("contextMenuStrip1").Click DataTable("contextMenuStrip1_X_4", dtGlobalSheet), DataTable("contextMenuStrip1_Y_4", dtGlobalSheet), micRightBtn
```

`micRightBtn` can also be replaced with `Click` later.